# How to change form in twig input text

Tags: symfony, twig

i generate new.html.twig  by CRUD the file is:

## Service creation

```
{{ form(form) }}

    <ul class="record_actions">
<li>
    <a href="{{ path('service') }}">
        Back to the list
    </a>
</li>
```

i need him in this  form :
can someone help me how i can override twig.
and think's.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about "how to customize form in symfony2" then here is an excellent [article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) on it. 
Simplest way to customize part of your form twig, is doing something like it:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block integer_widget %}
    <div class="integer_widget">
        {% set type = type|default('number') %}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {# ... render the form #}

    {{ form_row(form.age) }}
{% endblock %}
```

on the link I provided, there are many examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="$" method="POST" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="textfield" class="control-label">Brand Name</label>

      <div class="controls">
        {{ form_widget(form.brandName,{'attr':{'class':'input-xlarge','data-rule-required':'true'} }) }}
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-actions">
      {{ form_widget(form.submit,{'attr':{'class':'btn btn-primary','value':'Save changes'} }) }}
   </div>
  {{ form_rest(form) }}
</form>
```